# How to access a Dart class in a unit test

Tags: dart

Using Dart Milestone 4 version 21658

I'm new to Dart.  I created a class.  I want to unit test it.  Both the class and the unit test are in the same Dart project created using the Dart Editor.  I don't know how to make the unit test see my class. How can I do this?

**Project Name:** 
DartExp

**Directory structure:**

```
src/foo.dart
test/foo_test.dart
```

**File contents:**

--- foo.dart begin ----

```dart
//library foo;

class Foo
{
  String bar;
}
```

--- foo.dart end ----

--- foo.dart begin ----

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

import 'package:DartExp/foo.dart';
import 'DartExp/foo.dart';
import 'foo.dart';
import 'src/foo.dart';
import 'package:src/foo.dart';

main() {

  test('test Foo', () {

     Foo foo;

     //expect(1,1);
   });
}
```

--- foo.dart end ----

**Things I've tried:**

In the Dart Editor, in the file foo_test.dart, all my attempts to import foo.dart are marked as error because "...is not valid uri".  The editor also says the class Foo is undefined.
Removing all the foo.dart import statements, doesn't work either.
Making foo.dart into a library doesn't work either.

Documentation of the Dart import statement doesn't seem to give any examples for this common use case.

So, how do you import a class into a unit test in Dart?

Comment: @Greg: Thank you for taking time to answer my question.  Your answer made me see (and correct) a mistake in my original problem statement.  The unit test foo_test.dart is actually in the 'test' directory and not in 'lib'.   Sorry for the incorrect info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart uses the [Pub package manager](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/) for dependency management, and has a specific suggested package layout, which you can read about [on the Pub website](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html).

Try this and also run `pub install`.

**Directory structure:**

```
pubspec.yaml
lib/foo.dart
test/foo_test.dart
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: my_package
description: description
dev_dependencies:
   unittest: any
```

**lib/foo.dart:**

```dart
library foo;

class Foo {
}
```

**test/foo_test.dart:**

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:foo/foo.dart';

main() {
  test('test Foo', () {
     Foo foo;
   });
}
```

The `package:` URLs are resolved from the `packages` directory that Pub creates. To better understand this have a look at the contents of the `packages` directory after you run `pub install`.

So this:

```dart
import 'package:[package-name]/[file].dart';
```

Imports a library which is in the package named `[package-name]`, and found in the `lib` folder of this package in a file named `[file].dart`. (*Note*: a package can have multiple libraries.)

Comment: To my Java influenced mind, my Foo class is not a library. It seems better to put it in the 'src' directory.  If classes shouldn't be in src, then what is src for?  Dart Editor created src, so I assumed it was a standard directory [lib, test, src, web] Dart's package manager expects.  Your answer also makes me ask, must all Dart classes be designated as libraries?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're making a package, and want to export your libraries they need to be in lib. web is for files which need to accessible over http, so your top level dart script. I haven't noticed src at top level before. Though there's often a lib/src to hide implementation files. I typically layout my files so I can share them with pub.  But that probably doesn't apply for every type of app. For conventions, it's probably best to have a look on github, and see what other people are doing. http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Either of these paths make class Foo accessible in a Dart unit test.  src/foo.dart does not need to a library.  But even when it is, both import paths still work.

```
import '../src/foo.dart';
import 'package:../src/foo.dart';
```

By the way, as of 28-April-2013, [http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html]
doesn't have a top-level **src** directory (so I guess, my class is in a non-standard directory).

Comment: This trick used to work, but recently the whole path scheme changed in pub serve: /src/index.html turned into /index.html  So this solution is broken now, "An error occurred loading /src/foo.dart".  Any new ideas how to unit-test non-library code now?